# Dom tree travesal in BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, dom, beautifulsoup

I have an issue getting the dom tree traversal.

Example

```
<article>
   <h2>Google Chrome</h2>
   <span>
      <p>Google Chrome is a web browser</p>
      <p>Chrome is a web browser developed by google </p>
      <div>
         <div>
            <p>This is a leaf node</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </span>
</article>
```

I need the output of all the subtree/all the parents of all the leaf nodes

The find_all_previous() of BeautifulSoup is giving a solution but not a perfect one.

The required output is

- article-> h2-> Google Chrome
- article -> span -> p -> Google Chrome is a web browser
- article -> span -> p -> Chrome is a web browser developed by google
- article -> span -> div -> div -> p- > >This is a leaf node

Answer (score 4):

You can use recursion for the task:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<article>
   <h2>Google Chrome</h2>
   <span>
      <p>Google Chrome is a web browser</p>
      <p>Chrome is a web browser developed by google </p>
      <div>
         <div>
            <p>This is a leaf node</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </span>
</article>
"""


def traverse(t, current_path=None):
    if current_path is None:
        current_path = [t.name]

    for tag in t.find_all(recursive=False):
        if not tag.find():
            print(
                " -> ".join(
                    current_path + [tag.name, tag.find(text=True).strip()]
                )
            )
        else:
            traverse(tag, current_path + [tag.name])


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
traverse(soup.article)
```

Prints:

```
article -> h2 -> Google Chrome
article -> span -> p -> Google Chrome is a web browser
article -> span -> p -> Chrome is a web browser developed by google
article -> span -> div -> div -> p -> This is a leaf node
```